# Как подсчитать размер папки FAT

Tags: файловая-система, fat32

Ребята, приветсвтую.
Есть задача посчитать сколько место на диске с файловой системой FAT32 будет занимать папка с файлами.
Я знаю размер кластера файловой системы и это позволяет просто посчитать размер, необходимый именно для размещения всех файлов:

```
do 
    {
        if (fileinfo.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            if (wcscmp(fileinfo.cFileName, L".") !=0 && wcscmp(fileinfo.cFileName, L"..") != 0)
            {
                StringW path2;
                path2.Format(L"%s\\%s",path, fileinfo.cFileName);
                size += CalculateFatSize(path2, files, dirs);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fileSize = ((__int64)fileinfo.nFileSizeHigh << 32) | fileinfo.nFileSizeLow;
            unsigned int clustersInFiles = fileSize / clusterSize + (fileSize % clusterSize == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            size += (fileSize < clusterSize) ? clusterSize : clustersInFiles * clusterSize;
        }
    } while(FindNextFileW( hFile, &fileinfo ) != 0 );
```

Но насколько я знаю, для каждого файла в таблице FAT есть своя запись, которая содержит информацию о кластерах, в которых содержатся данные файла и т.д. Причем размер этой записи не фиксированный в случае с длинным именем файла (не уверен, что в случае с коротким именем файла этот размер фикисрованный).
То есть получается, что при подсчетете нужно еще как-то считать размер записи таблицы FAT для каждого файла.
Собственно, вопрос вот в чем, как определить этот размер?

Спасибо.

Comment: Вам размер записей о каталоге и файлах в нем или реальный размер, занимаемый файлами?

Comment: Владимир, меня интересует размер записей о каталоге и файлах в нем. Вроде как, реальный размер, занимаемый файлами, посчитать нетрудно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заранее оговорюсь, что говорю о FAT32, даже если говорю о FAT.

---

**Таблица FAT, находящаяся в начале диска**, содержит только общую информацию о диске и таблицу "связности кластеров", где для каждого кластера сказано, какой кластер в его цепочке следующий. Эта таблица выделяется заранее и имеет константный размер (для заданного размера тома и размера кластера на нём). Она всегда есть на диске и её место всегда "занято". Поэтому *учитывать расходы на место в ней в чём-либо, наверное, нет смысла.*

Далее **папки**. Это **обычные файлы**, с *особым атрибутом*, в которых лежат данные особой структуры, **по 32 байта на запись**. Для особо длинных имён **записей на один файл может быть несколько** (механизм LFN). Но все эти записи хранятся в файлах директории. Если вы какими-то низкоуровневыми средствами сможете получить именно **размер файла-директории**, то большего вам и не потребуется.

Занимаемое место, таким образом, будет суммой размеров всех {файлов папок} и указываемых ею файлов, рекурсивно.

---

Например, для структуры:

```
folder
|- 000000
|  ...
|  ...
|- 999999
```

...где в файлах `000000`-`999999` (всего миллион файлов) находится по 6 байт данных (их имена) данные будут разбиты следующим образом:

- (1 000 000 кластеров) По одному кластеру на содержимое каждого файла из `000000`-`999999` — потреблённое реальное дисковое место зависит от размера кластера, очевидно.

  - **Только содержимое файлов**. Про данные **о** файлах будет далее.
  - 6 байт заведомо меньше любого встречающегося в FAT32 кластера, поэтому будет всего по одному кластеру.
- (32 000 000 байт) **Данные о файлах хранятся в 32-байтных записях** в *файле* `folder` с атрибутом *directory*. **Как его содержимое.** Просто подряд. Механизмы работы с файловой системой могут не позволять его открывать просто как файл, но внутри он именно бинарным файлом и является.

  - Реальное потреблённое дисковое место:

    ```
    размер_кластера * округлить_вверх(32_000_000 / размер_кластера)
    ```
- (0 байт *в используемом пространстве*) Вышеуказанный файл не влезет в один кластер. Поэтому при его чтении надо будет смотреть в таблицу FAT (в начале диска) на предмет номера кластера, в котором хранится продолжение.

  - Но поскольку эта таблица выделяется заранее ещё при построении файловой системы, учитывать её объём мало смысла.
- (32 байта, *может быть*) Информация о `folder` хранится в его родительской папке среди данных о прочих файлах/папках (FAT, если вы ещё не догадались, применяет одинаковые механизмы для их хранения) рядом с `folder`.

  - Нужна ради номера первого кластера списка файлов.
  - ...но если это корень диска, то соответствующий номер хранится в *заголовке диска*, который является частью служебных структур файловой системы и учитывать его бессмысленно. А соответствующей 32-байтной записи в этом случае не существует.

Comment: представьте папка содержит файлы, названные по порядку: 000000..999999, которые содержат только своё имя (6 байт в ascii). Сколько места *на диске* эта папка с миллионом файлов может потребовать (примерно)?

Comment: @jfs следуя моей логике, папка 32млн байт + ceil до целого числа кластеров. Это если нет трюков с LFN, а при таких именах их быть не должно. Плюс файлы, по кластеру на штуку.

Comment: Не понял. Не могли бы вы обновить ответ и подробно расписать какие байты куда на диск пишутся в этом случае? Например, объяснить почему ответ не ~4K*1000_000? (если размер кластера 4K)

Comment: @jfs `4k*1_000_000 + 4k * ceil(32_000_000 / 4k) [+ 32]`. Привёл пример в ответе.

Comment: D-side, спасибо за разъяснение. То есть, как я понял, на каждый файл с коротким именем дополнительно отводится 32 байта для данных о файле. А как быть в ситуации с длинным именем файла или папки?

Comment: @user3113356 в зависимости от длины названия добавляется ещё сколько-то (но всегда целое число) 32-байтных записей **до** главной (с коротким именем, она есть всегда). К сожалению, я не настолько детально помню механизм LFN, чтобы сказать, сколько именно. В этих записях кроме собственно имени есть ещё опознавательный знак LFN и, вроде, что-то ещё.

Comment: +1. Случай вырожденный, но хорошо иллюстрирует, что сумма размеров файлов (6MB) может быть меньше размера служебной информации (32M—размер, который  автор вопроса хочет узнать) и существенно меньше фактически занимаемого места на диске (4GB)—в предположении, что действительная картина соответствует тому что в ответе написано.

Comment: @D-side, получается, что бы посчитать размер, занимаемый папкой, в которой содержатся только файлы с коротким именем, нужно добавить что то типа: 'if(len(filename) <=11) size+= 32 '. Так?

Comment: @user3113356 почти: плюс поправка на целое число кластеров, т. к. этот список хранится внутри папки как содержимое её файла.

Comment: @D-side, понял вас. Спасибо. Еще один глупый вопрос: мжно ли считать, что на каждые 11 символов имени приходится одна запись в таблице? Я имею в виду, что если имя состоит из 31 символа, то для его размещения в таблице будет выделено три записи по 32 байта?

Comment: @user3113356 я выше упомянул, что не помню :) Вы можете найти спецификацию FAT32 и найти там этот момент. Я довольно давно её читал.

Comment: @D-side, я прочитал [спецификацию](http://read.pudn.com/downloads77/ebook/294884/FAT32%20Spec%20(SDA%20Contribution).pdf), не всю, правда, а только Section 7. Исходя из прочитанного и приведенного примера я понял, что для long name, к Short directory entry прибавляется по одной long dir entry на каждые 13 символов имени. Понимаю, что нагло, но не могли бы вы глянуть материал по ссылке и проверить правильно ли я понял? Спасибо.

Comment: @rudolfninja судя по "The following example is provided to illustrate how a long name is stored across several long name directory entries. Names are also NULL terminated and padded with 0xFFFF characters in order to detect corruption of long name fields. A name that fits exactly in a set of long name directory entries (i.e. is an integer multiple of 13) is not NULL terminated and not padded with 0xFFFF." да, по 13 символов на запись.